# expand collapse cells in android

Tags: android, android-listview, expandablelistview

I am pretty new to android and I have a good iphone background. I need to know whether it is possible to have a expandablelistview inside a listview ?. If yes please let me know how to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I need to know whether it is possible to have a expandablelistview inside a listview ?

No, sorry. You cannot generally put scrollable things inside of other scrollable things, at least when they scroll in the same direction, as they fight over the touch events.

Answer (score 0):

There is an expandable listview demo in sdk for each version of android. It should be in a location like

```
E:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk-windows\samples\android-8\ApiDemos
```

Create a project from existing source in eclipse and you can check its source to understand how it works.